# Acquire server side API key for my Google account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-account

I am trying to get account credentials for my Google account which can be stored in a command line file. The script expects these 3 parameters to be set.

```
local client_id = ""
local client_secret = ""
local refresh_token = ""
```

So I expect I need some kind of OAuth token which will never be invalidated.

Does anyone know how to acquire it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the client id and the client secret from the Google dev console. You get the refresh token by doing a one-time authorization.

All of the steps are detailed in this answer [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)

Be very careful about how you secure the refresh token. It acts like a username/password for your Drive account, so could be used by "bad dudes". It's a good idea to use the most restrictive scope (step 8 in the above list). drive.file is a good choice if your script is uploading. If your script needs to download files, try drive.readonly.